# Branch.io event logging

Tags: branch.io

I am following the below link for logging ecommerce event in branch.io
https://github.com/BranchMetrics/branch-deep-linking-public-api#logging-commerce-events
I am using the same request as mentioned in the link.

but the details are not getting captured in branch.io dashboard.

I am getting "branch_view_enabled": false as a response.

Please help me out if there is any issue in settings ? or explicitly I will have to do something for seeing the events in the dashboard.

A response will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is Jackie from Branch. 
We are not yet supporting v2/events for commerce yet which is why you weren't able to track it on the dashboard.

Moving forward, please use v1 event request following our official documentation [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/api/#event-create-commerce). I've also included a sample commerce request for your information. In the meantime, we will update the commerce information on our github page so as not to cause any confusion.

```
curl -X POST https://api.branch.io/v1/event \
  -d '{
  "branch_key": "your_Branch_key",
  "identity": "222",
  "event": "purchase",
  "metadata": {
    "hello": "world",
    "custom_data": "this"
  },
  "commerce_data": {
    "revenue": 50.0,
    "currency": "USD",
    "transaction_id": "foo-transaction-id",
    "shipping": 0.0,
    "tax": 5.0,
    "affiliation": "foo-affiliation",
    "products": [
      {
        "sku": "foo-sku-1",
        "name": "foo-item-1",
        "price": 45.00,
        "quantity": 1,
        "brand": "foo-brand",
        "category": "Electronics",
        "variant": "foo-variant-1"
      },
      {
        "sku": "foo-sku-2",
        "price": 2.50,
        "quantity": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

Hope this helps. Please feel free to contact us directly if you have any other questions or issues at support@branch.io.

Best,

Jackie

Comment: hi Jackie, I am using android sdk and has similar issue. Can you please suggest a work around for android sdk?

Comment: Hi there! The solution above is regarding API request which is irrespective of the mobile OS. If you are looking for information on tracking commerce events via the Android SDK, here's our documentation on the topic: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#track-commerce

Comment: @JackieChoi as far as today I'm still getting this response using api v2 with requests, `https://api2.branch.io/v2/event/standard` with `COMPLETE_REGISTRATION` and `https://api2.branch.io/v2/event/custom` with `picture swiped`. Any suggestion here?

Comment: @jzeferino Our team will be happy to look further into this for you. Can you send an email to integrations@branch.io with the details? Please include 1. steps to reproduce, 2. expected result and 3. actual result in your message!

Comment: Great! To close the loop, we can now update on the v2 commerce events.

Comment: I am also getting this error when trying to log a custom event named "UNLOCK_ACHIEVEMENT". Should this still be an issue?

Comment: Hi. I am getting "branch_view_enabled": false for all custom events that I log using branch SDK on my android app. Can you help me understand why no events are showing up on my Branch Dashboard?

Comment: Hi @JackieChoi, Can we map our domain on branch.io? I am getting below error, Domain is incorrectly set up; please use the nameservers below as your NS record. A CNAME record is not required. If you've already done this, note that it can take up to several hours to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it like this
`new BranchEvent("Event Name")
                .addCustomDataProperty("Key", "Value")
                .logEvent(this);`

And it shows the event name on the branch dashboard under summary. And my log shows that internally it was targeting the v2. I am sending it through android

> https://api.branch.io/v2/event/custom